# FormData in multiple ajax request files

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to do a Ajax's loops requests for send files to an API but i don't not what I send at Ajax's data. When I do only file in upload I use the own formdata object and works very well. I tried use loop and each row send an individual file but it's doesn't works too:

Multiple files:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
for(i=0;i<3;i++){ // 3 length just for tests
    form_data.append('file', $('#myfile').prop('files')[i]);     
}                

for (var value of form_data.values()) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'URI',
        data: value,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!")
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("Error")
        }
        });
}
```